# Visual studio 2015 universal app push notification is missing

Tags: push-notification, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am trying to add push notification to my universal windows app.
In VS2013 I could use the add push notification wizard in order to do that and in VS2015 I couldn't find it.
Searching the web I found this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967191
Saying that the push notification wizard wasn't support in CTP4.
Am I missing something or the wizard isn't supported for VS2015?
How can I add support for push notification without the wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I verified it a bit more and it does seems that this is still not supported in VS2015, if you want to do it anyway the easiest way is to do it in VS2013 on a universal app project(windows or phone) and copy the right parts to the new solution.  hope they will add the wizard soon